# Split a string to print first two characters delimited by "-" In Bash

Tags: bash

I am listing the AWS region names.

```
us-east-1
ap-southeast-1
```

I want to split the string to print specific first characters delimited by `-` i.e. 'two characters'-'one character'-'one character'. So `us-east-1` should be printed as `use1` and `ap-southeast-1` should be printed as `aps1`

I have tried this and it's giving me expected results. I was thinking if there is a shorter way to achieve this.

```
region=us-east-1 
regionlen=$(echo -n $region | wc -m) 
echo $region | sed 's/-//' | cut -c 1-3,expr $regionlen - 2-expr $regionlen - 1
```

Comment: Your transformation will map both `ap-south-1` and `ap-southeast-1` to `aps1`, and both `cn-north-1` and `cn-northwest-1` to `cnn1`. Are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `sed`:

```
echo "$region" | sed -E 's/^(.[^-]?)[^-]*-(.)[^-]*-(.).*$/\1\2\3/'
```

Explanation: the `s/pattern/replacement/` command picks out the relevant parts of the region name, replacing the entire name with just the relevant bits. The pattern is:

```
^         - the beginning of the string
(.[^-]?)  - the first character, and another (if it's not a dash)
[^-]*     - any more things up to a dash
-         - a dash (the first one)
(.)       - The first character of the second word
[^-]*-    - the rest of the second word, then the dash
(.)       - The first character of the third word
.*$       - Anything remaining through the end
```

The bits in parentheses get captured, so `\1\2\3` pulls them out and replaces the whole thing with just those.

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` influencing field splitting step of parameter expansion:

```
$ str=us-east-2
$ IFS=- eval 'set -- $str'
$ echo $#
3
$ echo $1
us
$ echo $2
east
$ echo $3
```

No external utilities; just processing in the language.

This is how smartly written build configuration scripts parse version numbers like `1.13.4` and architecture strings  like `i386-gnu-linux`.

The `eval` can be avoided, if we save and restore `IFS`.

```
$ save_ifs=$IFS; set -- $str; IFS=$save_ifs
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash, and assuming that you need to distinguish between things like southwest and southeast:

```
s=ap-southwest-1

a=${s:0:2}
b=${s#*-}
b=${b%-*}
c=${s##*-}

bb=
case "$b" in
south*) bb+=s ;;&
north*) bb+=n ;;&
*east*) bb+=e ;;
*west*) bb+=w ;;
esac

echo "$a$bb$c"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
region="us-east-1"
echo "$region" | (IFS=- read -r a b c; echo "$a${b:0:1}${c:0:1}")
use1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` -

```
$: printf "us-east-1\nap-southeast-1\n" |
     sed -E 's/-(.)[^-]*/\1/g'
```

To keep noncardinal specifications like `southeast` distinct from `south` at the cost of adding an optional additional character -

```
$: printf "us-east-1\nap-southeast-1\n" |
   sed -E '
    s/north/n/;
    s/south/s/;
    s/east/e/;
    s/west/w/;
    s/-//g;'
```

If you could have `south-southwest`, add `g` to those directional reductions.

if you MUST have exactly 4 characters of output, I recommend mapping the eight or 16 map directions to specific characters, so that north is N, northeast is maybe O and northwest M... that sort of thing.